# VM299:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I am trying to get data using ajax request following is ajax request.

```
document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
                    $('body').css('overflow','hidden');
                    $.ajax({  
                        type: 'POST',  
                        url: 'techtest.php', 
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: { id: val },
                        success: function(response, status, xhr){ 
                            console.log(response.array[1]);
                            document.getElementById('tech_about_me').innerHTML = response.array[0];
                            document.getElementById('tech_assest_group').innerHTML = response.array[1];
                            document.getElementById('tech_skill_group').innerHTML = response.array[2]+""+response.array[3];
                            document.getElementById('tech_address').innerHTML = response.array[4];


                        },
                        error: function(data,XMLHttpRequest,xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                            console.log("Status: " + textStatus); console.log("Error: " + errorThrown); 
                            var err =  JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                            console.log(err.Message);

                            var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                            alert(json.error);
                        }  
                    });
```

But I am receiving error " VM299:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0     at JSON.parse ()"

following is my code to return json

```
<?php
 header("Content-Type: application/json");
 include "../common/config.php";
 include"../includes.php";
 include"session.php";
 // print_r('<script>console.log('.$_POST['id'].')</script>');
 $technician_details=$db->get_a_line("select * from user where user_id='".$_POST['id']."'");
 $about_me=$technician_details['about_me'];
 $address=$technician_details['address'];
 $assest_group=$technician_details['assest_group'];
 $skill_group=$technician_details['skill_group'];
 $skill_list=$technician_details['skill_list'];
 $data = array();
 $data[]=$about_me;
 $data[]=$assest_group;
 $data[]=$skill_group; 
 $data[]=$skill_list;
 $data[]=$address;
 $json_data = array(

        "recordsTotal"    => '5',  // total number of records
        "array"            => $data   // total data array
        );

 echo json_encode($json_data);  // send data as json format
 ?>
```

It was working before. but while testing yesterday i noticed it is giving error on pc's other than my local. from tomorrow morning it started giving same error on local to. Please help out.

Comment: whilst not an answer to your question it is worth noting that your code is vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: chances are, something you're trying to JSON.parse is `undefined`

Comment: thank you. gonna work on that @RamRaider

Comment: is the above PHP everything in `techtest.php` ? Is there any blank space before the opening PHP tag? Are any of the included files using `echo` or `print`?

Comment: No there is no blank space before php and  and there is no echo or print in included files @RamRaider

Comment: Look at the response in the Network tab of the browser. There's probably something before the JSON.

Comment: you might try modifying your `error` callback to be simply `error: function(e) {  console.log(e); }  ` and possibly try adding `exit( json_encode( array(1,2,3,4,5) ) );` before any include statements to see if that works OK

Comment: Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.invokeGetter(<anonymous>)

Comment: @RamRaider not working even with exit( json_encode( array(1,2,3,4,5) ) );

Comment: didn't find anything before json in network tab @Barmar

Comment: I tried to put datatype as text so, in success response is blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your last comment I quickly put together a small test to emulate what your script is doing. This works OK.

I suggest testing `as-is` first then, if you are happy that it is ok, uncomment the `include` lines and test again. Then, if that works try using the actual db query etc

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        if( !empty( $_POST['id'] ) ){
            /*

            # are these being included correctly?
            include '../common/config.php';
            include '../includes.php';
            include 'session.php';


            */


            # to emulate db query and results
            $id=filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
            $sql=sprintf( 'select * from user where user_id="%s"',$id );

            $payload=array(
                'about'         =>  'From db - all about user - based upon id '.$id,
                'assetgroup'    =>  'From db - which asset group',
                'skillgroup'    =>  'From db - which skill group',
                'skilllist'     =>  'from db - what skills',
                'address'       =>  'from db - address of tech'
            );
            $data = array(
                'recordsTotal'  =>  count( $payload ),
                'data'          =>  $payload,
                'sql'           =>  $sql
            );
            header( 'Content-Type: application/json' );
            exit( json_encode( $data ) );
        }
        exit('error');
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>basic jquery - error parsing response</title>
        <script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js'></script>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{

                const node=function(id){
                    return document.getElementById( id )
                };

                let val=303;

                $.ajax({  
                    type:'POST',  
                    url:location.href,  //techtest.php
                    dataType:'json',
                    data:{ id: val },
                    success:function( r ){
                        node('tech_about_me').innerHTML = r.data.about;
                        node('tech_assest_group').innerHTML = r.data.assetgroup;
                        node('tech_skill_group').innerHTML = r.data.skillgroup+" "+r.data.skilllist;
                        node('tech_address').innerHTML = r.data.address;

                        console.info( r.sql, r.recordsTotal )
                    },
                    error: function(e) { alert(e); }  
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='tech_about_me'></div>
        <div id='tech_assest_group'></div>
        <div id='tech_skill_group'></div>
        <div id='tech_address'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. one of included file had more includes. Probably there was some issue.

Comment: good - glad that you are now past that little hurdle. Good luck

Comment: yeahh. Now gonna solve hurdles of sql injections. project is full of it. :D @RamRaider